Running Iperf3 binary on android 14
For an app I am making, I need to be able to perform network bandwidth and down/upload speed tests using iPerf3. On the official iPerf website (https://iperf.fr/iperf-doc.php) I found a binary that works on my device (arm64-v8a).
The problem I am facing now is that i need to be able to run this binary without ROOT. While the binary itself runs fine, I can't create a stream due to lack of permissions.
If somebody knows an alternative route I can take that doesn't involve rooting, or a functional API, I would be forever grateful!
I tried to run the file through the app (run-as <package.name>) which has permissions INTERNET and ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE (I'm pretty sure I don't even need the second one).
I also checked I had the necessary permissions to execute the file by using chmod +x but as I said before, the binary runs, it just cant establish a correct connection.
I believe it has something to do with the fact that the file using -Z shows up as s0 (security level untrusted)

After further investigation, I can confirm that the app can not run the binary.
Shell, as expected, can run it just fine (from a different location), but when in private storage, the app cannot.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
